# SHA1 hash encoded with base64 results not consistent?

Tags: encoding, sha

When i take a hash of user input `test123+` i get the following base64 result:-
`YaddchSU52yztwIMdtHzkg3p1oA=`
The results have been obtained using the online sha1 [convertor](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator)

I m failing to understand how does this work?  When i take just convert `test123+` using sha1 i get `d478f2a272d7830987e8cd1c732af606`.  Now when i do the base64 encoding on this input i get this result `ZDQ3OGYyYTI3MmQ3ODMwOTg3ZThjZDFjNzMyYWY2MDY=`

Why are two base64 conversion so different?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've generating the base64 encoding of the ASCII hex string, rather than the raw bytes of the hash function's output.

Comment: So what you are saying the link i included above is using raw bytes to convert it into base64?

Comment: Yes, that's the case.

Comment: But when i want to go back and retrieve the original string using hex decoding i don't get test123+ instead i get some garbage? I'm using 61a75d721494e76cb3b7020c76d1f3920de9d680 is this because it is using raw byes? right

Comment: Yep. The "garbage" you see is the ASCII representation of the raw bytes produced by the hash.

Comment: So, this method is pretty much safe ; and beats hash recovery.

Comment: It definitely does NOT beat "recovery" just to be represented by text instead of binary (Sorry if I sound angry).

Comment: I guess i was not properly explained why i was getting the garbage output until i investigate the issue myself. I was direct decoding the base64 and not doing conversion when i did a base64->hex conversion there was no garbage i got the hex value which i use in sha1 decoder to get original value (test123+)